Howto: spx + roadrunner
I have docker + laravel + roadrunner + spx profiler
Here is written that it is not complatible with roadrunner
But here was written solution for Laravel. But I got an error for call spx_profiler_start() -  profiling is not enabled
I have in php.ini:
extension=spx.so
spx.http_enabled=1
spx.http_profiling_enabled=1
spx.http_key='dev'
spx.http_ip_whitelist='*' 
spx.data_dir=/spx_dumps

Also doesn't load panel on http://localhost/?SPX_KEY=dev&SPX_UI_URI=/
But for console I got dump. But I can't view it without panel.
Are any ideas? TNX.

Solution
For profiling add this envs in your docker-compose.yml
environment:
    SPX_ENABLED: 1
    SPX_AUTO_START: 0
    SPX_REPORT: full

And profiling can be enabled by calling spx_profiler_start();
For Laravel this can be added in some middleware from here like this:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Spx
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): mixed
    {
        $local = config('app.env') === 'local';
        if($local && function_exists('spx_profiler_start')) {
            spx_profiler_start();
        }
        try {
            $return = $next($request);
        } finally {
            if ($local && function_exists('spx_profiler_stop')) {
                spx_profiler_stop();
            }
        }

        return $return;
    }
}

registered in App\Http\Kernel::$middleware
For viewing profiles use some server with php-fpm for example.
